# ScrollView keeps overlapping items below it

Tags: android, xml, button, scrollview

I have a ScrollView, and below it two horizontally aligned buttons. I want the buttons to be A) at the bottom of the window when the scrollview doesn't fill the entire window, and B) to stay below the scrollview when it IS larger than the window.

Currently, the buttons are successfully placed at the bottom of the screen when the scrollview isn't filling the whole window, but when the scrollview has too much data to fit in the window (e.g. when the phone is turned to landscape view) the scrollview data overlaps over the buttons.

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to meet both of these conditions simultaneously just by using XML. Perhaps I've no choice but to introduce some programmatic checking? Anyway, here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/groupHeader" />     


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/groupHeader" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/groupCreate" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/groupcreate_button_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/groupcreate_button_new" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/groupcreate_button_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/groupcreate_button_next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any and all assistance in advance.

EDIT:

I should probably mention that the LinearLayout "groupCreate" inside the ScrollView in question is created empty, but immediately has Views added to it programmatically, which is what causes it to take up space and sometimes overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xml

I have made few changes in your xml, including id's and other stuff just to test on my device.
Later you can change according to yours.

```
<LinearLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Group Header"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        // You can put other View inside this scrollview

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/groupcreate_button_new"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/groupcreate_button_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Try and use it, and let me know whether it meets your requirement or not.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot  =)
edit: pardon the delay, had to shut off my laptop almost as soon as I posted this.

Comment: An added thought: can you help me understand why this worked, as opposed to the behavior I was originally experiencing? I'd much rather learn than blindly implement, I'm sure you understand.

Comment: Actually you are using Relative layout as parent view in your UI. Although there is no harm using relative layout,its beautiful if you can handle it. Relative layout maintains a relationship between   parent view and child views. Talking about your two buttons at the bottom, actually they are aligned on the top of your parent view including scroll view. So your buttons does not care about the space taken up by your scroll view, they will remain at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: and sorry if i misunderstood your commented query.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem myself. The solution of @A.R is working, but I feel is missing a bit of explanation. You have to use **LinearLayout** to be able to add **android:layout_weight** to the child views, which does all the "magic". Adding android:layout_weight = 1 to both views forces android to render both views, and excludes the overlapping.
Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/groupcreate_button_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`fillViewPort`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport) attribute of a ScrollView. Romain Guy has demonstrated its use well [on his blog](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/comment-page-1/).

Comment: I looked into this, but simply adding a "fillViewPort="true" didn't do the trick; I think I'd have had to move all of the other views inside the ScrollView. Which may have worked, but I tried the answer above and it worked as-is. Shame, as I'd hoped there was an answer as simple as switching a flag. Thanks though  =)

Comment: To use the `fillViewPort` attribute, you would probably also have needed to include at least one view (either with content, or an empty spacer `View`) that used a weight inside the `LinearLayout` as Romain did. In fact, the latter appears to be what the accepted answer does. I was hoping to point in you the right direction so you could read up on the details, rather than drop a full answer without context.

Comment: Understood and appreciated. I'm still not always reliably able to predict how my XML will be displayed, which is why I'm trying to get a better understanding of what's happening here and why.